What happens if I stop my Pro subscription to Flickr?
What happens if I stop my Pro subscription to Flickr?

Can I upload more photos (I have about 14 GB of photos there, far less than 1 TB)?
Do old photos get deleted or inaccessible (to edit / to view)?


If you stop your subscription in Flickr:

You can upload if you have less than 1000 photos/videos. If you have more you will not be able to upload new. Not sure about editing. You can of course delete photos.
After some period your oldest photos will be deleted till you reach the count of 1000. The deletion will start (AFAIK) from the oldest to the newest.

